# How can I redirect to a URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

How can I redirect the viewer to a URL?

I noticed that someone asked [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery/506004#506004), but I'm not exactly sure where this should go.

I have tried in the controller with:
`window.location.replace("http://192.168.1.109/MWT/Taglist/ShowMap" + LastId);`
and in the view with:

```
<% if (BreakCount >= 8) {  
    var url = "http://192.168.1.109/MWT/Taglist/ShowMap" + LastId;  
    window.location.replace(url);  
} %>
```

Neither of these work. In both places places `window` has a red squiggly line underneath it and when I hover over it the message says "The name 'window' does not exist in the current context."

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

=D

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Your question is tagged MVC 3, so I'll give you the answer for that in spite of the JavaScript example you listed. In your controller class use this code:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    // Use this for an action
    return RedirectToAction("ActionName");
    // Use this for a URL
    return Redirect("http://192.168.1.109/MWT/Taglist/ShowMap" + LastId);
}
```

This is occuring on the server, meaning that the client browser recieves a redirect response for which the browser will likely submit an additional request. If you return a page with JavaScript it will have to load a page, run the JavaScript (presuming it is enable on the client's browser), the load the next page. Among other problems, using JavaScript means that if the user presses the back button they will be repeatedly redirected again back to the page they are currently on.

Comment: Thanks!  I have my program working correctly with the help of your code.

Answer (score 6):

Inside your controller call `return RedirectToAction()`.

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

or, it you use [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) (and you should ;-))

```
public ActionResult MyAction() {

    return RedirectToAction(MVC.Home.Index());
}
```

Do not put the `if` statement in the view - that's not the MVC way. It is the responsibility of the controller to decide whether to redirect to a different view.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Make sure the LastId variable is defined
    var LastId = '123';
    <% if (BreakCount >= 8) { %>
        var url = "http://192.168.1.109/MWT/Taglist/ShowMap" + LastId;
        window.location.replace(url);
    <% } %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var id = '123';
   location.href = "http://192.168.1.109/MWT/Taglist/ShowMap/" + id;
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this :

top.location.href = "/url";