# How to use RedirectToAction to redirecto to a position in the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, redirecttoaction

I am using MVC4, C# and visual studio ultimate 2013 in a project.

I am redirecting a user to an index page after submiting a form. However, this webpage has 2 tabs, and I want to redirect the user to the second tab, instead of the first one.

I have a Controller called `Material`, with an `Index` action, which sends the user to the `Index` View.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

This View is made of two partial Views, `_Materials` and `_Packages`.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Materials" data-toggle="tab">Materials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Packages" data-toggle="tab">Packages</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="Materials">
            @Html.Action("Materials", "Material")
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="Packages">
            @Html.Action("Packages", "Package")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After performing a serie of actions in another section of the application, I which to redirect the user to the `/Material` page, to the second tab, but I have no idea how to do it !

Currently I am using this code, which always redirects to the first tab:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Material");
```

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985068/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-url you'll also need to add a hash to the end of the url ex.  www.foobar.com/fizz#Packages

Comment: How do I add an # character to the URL ? It does not seem to be escaped properly :S

Comment: Also, I do not see how that solves my problem =(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use something like `RedirectToAction` because it does not have any capability of appending a URL fragment. What you can do is use something like `Redirect` which just takes a URL string, and then use the URL helper to still dynamically generate the action URL for you:

```
return Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Material") + "#Package");
```

In other words, `Url.Action` will generate the main URL for you and return it as a string. You can then append the fragment to this string before finally redirecting.

Comment: I used the same method but it's going up again after coming to `#myDivId`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the

Redirect method

```
Redirect("www.sitename.com/material/index#Package");
```

or

```
string fragment = "Package";
Redirect("www.sitename.com/material/index#" + fragment);
```

The #Package is what is called a Fragment Identifier, that will focus your browser on the part of the page with the id of Package.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply *write an Ajax call* to pass to the controller and in case of `success`, append `#tab` to the url parameter. for example use this: